# Is the following cyclic group test wrong in WolframAlpha?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

Please see here
[Cyclic group test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20the%20group%20Z_13%C3%97Z_12%20cyclic%3F)

Isn't this a mistake?  Isn't this a cyclic group generated by $(5,1)$ ? thank you!

Comment: Try posting this on mathematica.se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Wolfram alpha is wrong. [It says also the group $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_2$ is not cyclic!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+the+group+Z_3%C3%97Z_2+cyclic%3F) , which is false.

---

The group $\Bbb Z_{13} \times \Bbb Z_{12}$ is cyclic of order $156$ since $\gcd\{13,12\}=1$ and $(5,1)$ is of order $ \text{lcm}\{13,12\}=156$, so $$\langle (5,1) \rangle=\Bbb Z_{13} \times \Bbb Z_{12}$$

Comment: Also see this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=direct+product+Z3+%C3%97+Z2) . It already says $\Bbb{Z}_3 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ is not cyclic but in this link, it list the six elements of this group as $1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5$. That is every element can be written as $a^n$ .which is exactly the cyclic group notation but nevertheless  it says the group is not cyclic!  which is false!